# Integration of PayPal as payment method - Manage DIFFERENT accounts

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to understand how to use PayPal to add a payment method to my web application.

[image: Scenario]

**The scenario is the following:**
I'm the owner of an e-commerce Platform (Blue Rectangle).

I sell accounts to access my platform to shop owners (Green Rectangles).

When I sell an account to some shop owner (Green Rectangles), I actually create an area where my customer (Green Rectangles) can access and insert his products etc etc...

The 'Green Rectangles' in the end have a page with a list of all the products he put in there.

Those products can be sold to the final customer (Yellow Rectangles).

**What I need:**
So I need to configure PayPal in order to provide to the 'Green Rectangles' a method to get paid from the 'Yellow Rectangles' (that are the shop owner and his customers)
And also, I need to provide to myself (Blue Rectangle) a method to get paid from 'Green Rectangles' (the shop owner that decides to use my service, so he have to pay an annual quota).

It's possibile to this such a thing with PayPal?
It is like eBay, there are different shops, when you buy you pay to the shop, even if all the shops are on eBay itself.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal has a partner program for this type of thing: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/partner-program/global-programs

But whether you'll get a response and they'll work with your business on this is another question.

Short of that, with publicly-documented APIs, there isn't a particularly good way to accomplish charging a "platform fee" per transaction, if that's essentially what you're asking.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.
Clicking the link send me to PayPal website but it show "Page not found".

Actually I don't need to get a fee for each product a 'Green Rectangle' sells.

I only need to know if it's possibile to provide to the 'Green Rectangle' a way to get paid online from his customer when he sells some products in the shop provided from my service
.
Then I also need to be paid for the annual quota that the 'Green Rectangle' has to pay to use my service

Comment: They can go to https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications to obtain a clientID and secret,and enter that information into your configuration interface.  As for charging them, you could send them a PayPal invoice or have your own checkout button where they sign up for the service.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I took a look and it seems to be not so easy.
I'm considering to use stripe instead